# bars not showing in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am modifying [this chart sample](http://jsfiddle.net/z4aZ4/160/) to go with my sample data.

I removed the functions generating random data and have put my hardcoded sample data. Now, everything is showing up, but not the bars.

I am getting several errors that are of the same type:

```
Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

and

```
Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
```

I believe the input values are numbers, still I am getting these errors.

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/z4aZ4/163/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in an incorrect format. The pairs should be objects with `x` and `y` properties, not arrays.

This should do it:

```
data.forEach(function(datum){
    datum.values = datum.values.map(function(el){
        return {x:el[0], y:el[1]}
    });
})
```

Comment: Thats shows the bars now. But the chart looks weird. The y-axis scale is very tiny and no x-tick and y-tick labels are shown. http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/z4aZ4/170/

Comment: @RahulDesai remove the `chart.xAxis.tickValues` setting. It's no longer needed, nvd3 does that by itself.

Comment: That certainly helps! My only concern right now is why is the y-axis scale messed up? Why is the max-value 14k shown there? http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/z4aZ4/173/

Comment: @RahulDesai that is the sum of the maximum values for each data set. I guess it's how the stacked graph works.